# SystemJS, importing a module within a bundle file

Tags: angular, systemjs, typescript1.8

We have currently have a module-per-file setup with Typescript 1.8.10, Angular 2 beta.08 (can't upgrade, yet), and SystemJS 0.19.25.  We are also using gulp-typescript 2.13.4 to actually build the files and move them to the /js/ directory.

We now want to move to a bundled file, where all modules are compressed and concatenated into a single file.  This part is working, but I can't get the main app component to load from angular 2.

Does the bootstrap file need to be on its own, or is there some way I can reference the file in SystemJS with `System.import`?  Currently, we specify a file (defualt extension of `.js`):

```
System.import( 'app/boot' )
            .then( null, console.error.bind( console ) );
```

This doesn't seem to work in the bundled file.  Is there a way to do something like this, where I can specify a module within the bundled file?:

```
System.import( 'app/boot', 'bundled-file' )
            .then( null, console.error.bind( console ) );
```

`app/boot` is the module name due to typescript's calculation of the root folder.  ('app' is the common root for all code files being compiled.) If there is any way to change this, as well, that would be fine.

I did include the bundled file in the `<head>` tag, above this import statement.  My initial attempt to import the bundle by file path seemed to have worked without showing any console errors, but the angular 2 app isn't being loaded.

Comment: what console errors do you get when adding the bundle as `<script>` tag after which you call `System.import( 'app/boot' ).then( null, console.error.bind( console ) );`?

Comment: @Hani - it is the `invalid token <` error, because it receives the html file for the index page when SystemJS attempts to get an invalid file at `mydomain.com/app/boot.js`.  Our site is currently treated as a single-page app, so any request for a non-existent file is returned the main html page.

Comment: that means your SystemJS configuration is not right, do you have `/// <amd-module name="boot" />` on top of your `.ts` file? If you're transpiling  to system you'll need that for bundling to work.

Comment: @Hani, I'm not transpiling. We're building prior to deployment, and tsconfig is using `system` for the module parameter.

Comment: SystemJS will import the bundled file, but I can't figure out (based on quick google searches) how to import/execute the main module.

Comment: You can only do that if the module has a name, your tsconfig.json has to have `module: "system"` and `moduleResolution: "node"` defined in it. After that the `<amd-module>` will define a named registration for each module once transpiled. By the way, bundle should be `.js` and not `.ts` so you need to transpile according to this. Once those are done, you can use your import statement. SystemJS will make an ajax request if it can't find a named registration `app/boot`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112436/discussion-between-ps2goat-and-hani).